# Custom no e-mail list

Tags: javascript, email

I am trying to write a code in Javascript that blocks users from e-mailing certain e-mails. Rather than blocking an entire domain (e.g. gmail.com), I was hoping to just block users from e-mailing one or two e-mails. This is to prevent our helpdesk agents from sending direct e-mails to our senior leadership team. Has anyone had any experience with this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? As you usually not send out mails through Javascript itself, why not implement such a filter in the technique that does this instead?

Comment: you mean in node.js?

Comment: So we use this CRM system (Freshdesk) online, the backend of Freshdesk is coded in Javascript. There is currently no function on Freshdesk to stop a user from e-mailing certain e-mails, we can block entire domains, but not individual e-mails.